# 6 elements in an array but only showing up as 1

Tags: python, arrays

i have an array :

```
[4, 4, 86, 59, 21, 38]
```

it as 6 elements in it,

```
CellNetInfopkt += struct.pack("b" * len(this_or_address_send_array), this_or_address_send_array)
```

this piece of code assigns a "b" for each element in the array, the number of "b"s is correct however the second part of the of the code, where each element is assigned to each b is not working i get the error :

```
 CellNetInfopkt += struct.pack("b" * len(this_or_address_send_array), this_or_address_send_array)
struct.error: pack expected 6 items for packing (got 1)
```

it seems as although it is taking the whole array as a single item and not 6, so the question is how can i configure this so it takes it as the 6 different values ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
CellNetInfopkt += struct.pack("b" * len(this_or_address_send_array), *this_or_address_send_array)
#  Notice the "*"                                                   ^^^
```

This is known as ["unpacking" argument lists](https://docs.python.org/2.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

Comment: would that assign the array to each "b" or each element of the array to each "b" ?

Comment: The 2nd one.  The * in front of the list makes the function treat the 6 element list just like 6 separate positional arguments.